# GwT Hangs on Development Mode

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt, extjs, gxt

[image]Hi,

Im using GwT / Sencha GxT when trying to deploy in Development Mode, my Gwt pages will not load. Does anyone know what could cause this issue? I just have a loading indicator that hangs.

Comment: I am able to access non GwT webpages and able to access back end information, just not GWT client side screens.

Hosted Mode / Client side debugging works well!

Comment: What do you see in the browser console or network tabs? Which resource is not loading?